# Dir globbing not recursing fully

Tags: ruby, glob

```
files = Dir[File.join(path, '**', '*.jpg')].each do |s| 
    puts s       
end
```

I have a bunch of subfolders within a directory and this snippet seems to go into some of the subdirectories, but skips most of them. How can I make it so that it recurses into all directories?

Also, should I be using `Find` instead? If so, could someone provide an example that does the same as above, namely finding .jpgs in all subdirectories?

**EDIT -**

Ok, so apparently when I do it with `.JPG` (capitalized) it finds all the files. Strange... How can I tell to find either of them?

Comment: You talk about 'recurses into all directories', but you select for jpg-files. Are there really jpg's in the subdirectories you expect? Are you missing jpgs?

Comment: You are working with Linux? In Windows it's no problem with capitalized filenames -- You can decide yourself, if it is a bug or a feature ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help with different extensions:

```
files = Dir[File.join(path, '**', '*.{jpg,JPG}')].each do |s| 
    puts s       
end
```

Comment: that's exactly what i ended up doing. Thanks! I'm on a Mac, for those who were curious.

Answer (score -4):

Obviously you forgot use glob method on Dir like:

```
 Dir.glob(File.join('**','*.jpg'))
```

Comment: From documentation: `Dir[ array ]`: Equivalent to calling Dir.glob